# How can I bulk update titles and alt tags for all my woocommerce product images?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, metadata

On an existing site (wordpress 4.5.2 with woocommerce) there are 5k products with all image names being numbers (ex: 94325.jpg) and no title and alt tag set.

How can I bulk update titles and alt tags of these product images to product name in order to improve seo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the standard Wordpress Media manager allows you to set these one at a time, I'm not aware of any plugin that allows you to do a batch update. Asking Woocommerce support would be a good option here.

Answer (score 0):

Disclosure: I am the developer of this plugin.

So WordPress stores attributes in two locations, one in the media library and another in the html of each image (which you can see if you choose to edit the image block as html). If your theme pulls the attributes from media library, then you can use this plugin and update image tile and alt text in bulk - https://wordpress.org/plugins/auto-image-attributes-from-filename-with-bulk-updater/

I also have Image Attributes Pro which will update both the media library and post html and can use post / product title / image filename / SEO keywords to generate all image attributes. You can find it here: https://imageattributespro.com/